# Android emlulator (AVD) crashes right away after launch on Ubuntu 20.4 LTS

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

Android emulator (AVD) crashes few seconds after the launch. The host machine has a Intel processor 8 cores with a GPU. I have `qemu-kvm` installed. Android that I am trying to emulate has version of 10.0+ with x86 image (although older versions of Android such as R, Lollipop, Kitkat also crashes). The  Android emulator was ran from command line so I have the log print. Can any one tell me how to fix this?

```
06-14 00:18:32.031   378   503 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:32.092   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:32.123   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.gsi.IGsid$Stub$Proxy
06-14 00:18:32.123   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.gsi.IGsid$Stub

06-14 00:18:32.927   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:32.932   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.location.-$$Lambda$AbstractListenerManager$Registration$TnkXgyOd99JHl00GzK6Oay_sYms
06-14 00:18:32.932   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.location.-$$Lambda$LocationManager$LocationListenerTransport$JzcdERl3Ha8sYr9NxFhb3gNOoCM
06-14 00:18:32.933   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.location.-$$Lambda$LocationManager$LocationListenerTransport$OaIkiu4R0h4pgFbCDDlNkbmPaps
06-14 00:18:32.933   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.location.-$$Lambda$LocationManager$LocationListenerTransport$vDJFuk-DvyNgQEXUO2Jkf2ZFeE8
06-14 00:18:32.933   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.location.-$$Lambda$LocationManager$LocationListenerTransport$vtBApnyHdgybRqRKlCt1NFEyfeQ
06-14 00:18:32.936   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioDevice$1
06-14 00:18:32.936   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioDevice
06-14 00:18:32.936   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioDeviceAddress$1
06-14 00:18:32.936   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioDeviceAddress
06-14 00:18:32.994   289   289 I zygote  : Thread[1,tid=289,Native,Thread*=0xe9884610,peer=0x13200260,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "libmedia_jni.so"
06-14 00:18:32.998   289   289 I zygote  : Thread[1,tid=289,Native,Thread*=0xe9884610,peer=0x13200260,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "libmedia_jni.so"
06-14 00:18:32.998   289   289 D MtpDeviceJNI: register_android_mtp_MtpDevice
06-14 00:18:32.998   289   289 I zygote  : Thread[1,tid=289,Native,Thread*=0xe9884610,peer=0x13200260,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "libmedia_jni.so"
06-14 00:18:32.999   289   289 I zygote  : Thread[1,tid=289,Native,Thread*=0xe9884610,peer=0x13200260,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "libmedia_jni.so"

06-14 00:18:33.008   378   503 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.028   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.034   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.-$$Lambda$NetworkStats$3raHHJpnJwsEAXnRXF2pK8-UDFY
06-14 00:18:33.034   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.-$$Lambda$NetworkStats$xvFSsVoR0k5s7Fhw1yPDPVIpx8A
06-14 00:18:33.076   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.NetworkScore$1
06-14 00:18:33.076   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.NetworkScore$Builder
06-14 00:18:33.076   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.NetworkScore
06-14 00:18:33.088   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.wifi.wificond.ChannelSettings$1
06-14 00:18:33.088   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.wifi.wificond.ChannelSettings
06-14 00:18:33.089   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.wifi.wificond.HiddenNetwork$1
06-14 00:18:33.089   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.wifi.wificond.HiddenNetwork
06-14 00:18:33.089   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.wifi.wificond.NativeScanResult$1
06-14 00:18:33.089   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.wifi.wificond.NativeScanResult
06-14 00:18:33.089   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.wifi.wificond.PnoNetwork$1
06-14 00:18:33.089   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.wifi.wificond.PnoNetwork
06-14 00:18:33.089   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.wifi.wificond.PnoSettings$1
06-14 00:18:33.089   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.wifi.wificond.PnoSettings
06-14 00:18:33.089   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.net.wifi.wificond.RadioChainInfo$1

06-14 00:18:33.095   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.os.-$$Lambda$PowerManager$1$-RL9hKNKSaGL1mmR-EjQ-Cm9KuA
06-14 00:18:33.109   378   503 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.130   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.permission.-$$Lambda$PermissionControllerManager$WcxnBH4VsthEHNc7qKClONaAHtQ
06-14 00:18:33.130   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.permission.-$$Lambda$PermissionControllerManager$u5bno-vHXoMY3ADbZMAlZp7v9oI
06-14 00:18:33.130   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.permission.-$$Lambda$PermissionControllerManager$yqGWw4vOTpW9pDZRlfJdxzYUsF0
06-14 00:18:33.132   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.229   378   503 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.232   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.235   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$1uNdvGRe99lTurQeP2pTQkZS7Vs
06-14 00:18:33.235   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$3AYVJXME-0OB4yixqaI-xr5L60o
06-14 00:18:33.235   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$7gZpRKvFmk92UeW5ehgYjTU1VJo
06-14 00:18:33.235   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$BEnQPWSMGANn8JYkd7Z9ykD6hTU
06-14 00:18:33.235   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$BJFxSgUMHRSttswNjrMRkS82g_c
06-14 00:18:33.235   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$BmipTxlu2pSFr1wevj-6L899tUY
06-14 00:18:33.235   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$D3Qz69humkpMXm7JAHU36dMvoyY
06-14 00:18:33.236   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$DrpO57uI0Rz8zN_EPJ4-5BrkiWs
06-14 00:18:33.236   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$E9hw_LXFliykadzCB_mw8nukNGI
06-14 00:18:33.236   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$F-YGB2a8GrHG6CB17lzASQZXVHI
06-14 00:18:33.236   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$LLJobItLwgTRjD_KrTiT4U-xUz0
06-14 00:18:33.236   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$MtX5gtAKHxLcUp_ibya6VO1zuoE
06-14 00:18:33.236   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$Rh4FuYaAZPAbrOYr6GGF6llSePE
06-14 00:18:33.236   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$YY3srkIkMm8vTSFJZHoiKzUUrGs
06-14 00:18:33.236   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$jNtyZYh5ZAuvyDZA_6f30zhW_dI
06-14 00:18:33.237   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$jTFXkqSnWC3uzh7LwzUV3m1AFOQ
06-14 00:18:33.237   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$jclAV5yU3RtV94suRvvhafvGuhw
06-14 00:18:33.237   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$jlNX9JiqGSNg9W49vDcKucKdeCI
06-14 00:18:33.237   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$mezBWc8HrQF0w9M2UHZzIjv5b5A
06-14 00:18:33.237   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$nxFDy8UzMc58xiN0nXxhJfBQdMI
06-14 00:18:33.237   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$r8YFiJlM_z19hwrY4PtaILOH2wA
06-14 00:18:33.237   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$vWj6-S8LaQStcrOXYYPgkxQlFg0
06-14 00:18:33.237   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$xyyTM70Sla35xFO0mn4N0yCuKGY
06-14 00:18:33.237   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$yGF2cJtJjwhRqDU8M4yzwgROulY
06-14 00:18:33.238   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.text.AndroidBidi$EmojiBidiOverride
06-14 00:18:33.255   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.util.StatsLogInternal
06-14 00:18:33.256   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.-$$Lambda$1kvF4JuyM42-wmyDVPAIYdPz1jE
06-14 00:18:33.257   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.-$$Lambda$InsetsController$HI9QZ2HvGm6iykc-WONz2KPG61Q
06-14 00:18:33.257   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.-$$Lambda$ViewRootImpl$YBiqAhbCbXVPSKdbE3K4rH2gpxI
06-14 00:18:33.257   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.-$$Lambda$ViewRootImpl$vBfxngTfPtkwcFoa96FB0CWn5ZI
06-14 00:18:33.263   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.IWindowContainer$Stub$Proxy
06-14 00:18:33.264   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.IWindowContainer$Stub
06-14 00:18:33.264   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.IWindowContainer
06-14 00:18:33.266   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.InsetsController$1
06-14 00:18:33.274   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.RenderNodeAnimator$1
06-14 00:18:33.274   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.RenderNodeAnimator$DelayedAnimationHelper
06-14 00:18:33.274   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.RenderNodeAnimatorSetHelper
06-14 00:18:33.274   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.SurfaceControl$PhysicalDisplayInfo
06-14 00:18:33.274   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.View$14
06-14 00:18:33.291   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.WindowContainerTransaction$1
06-14 00:18:33.291   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.WindowContainerTransaction
06-14 00:18:33.308   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$0biFK4yZBmWN1EO2wtnXskzuEcE
06-14 00:18:33.308   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$9N8WImc0VBjy2oxI_Gk5_Pbye_A
06-14 00:18:33.309   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$ActionsModelParamsSupplier$GCXILXtg_S2la6x__ANOhbYxetw
06-14 00:18:33.309   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$ActionsModelParamsSupplier$zElxNeuL3A8paTXvw8GWdpp4rFo
06-14 00:18:33.309   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$ActionsSuggestionsHelper$6oTtcn9bDE-u-8FbiyGdntqoQG0
06-14 00:18:33.309   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$ActionsSuggestionsHelper$YTQv8oPvlmJL4tITUFD4z4JWKRk
06-14 00:18:33.309   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$ActionsSuggestionsHelper$sY0w9od2zcl4YFel0lG4VB3vf7I
06-14 00:18:33.309   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$GenerateLinksLogger$vmbT_h7MLlbrIm0lJJwA-eHQhXk
06-14 00:18:33.309   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$L_UQMPjXwBN0ch4zL2dD82nf9RI
06-14 00:18:33.309   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$NxwbyZSxofZ4Z5SQhfXmtLQ1nxk
06-14 00:18:33.309   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$OGSS2qx6njxlnp0dnKb4lA3jnw8
06-14 00:18:33.309   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$TextClassifierImpl$RRbXefHgcUymI9-P95ArUyMvfbw
06-14 00:18:33.309   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$TextClassifierImpl$ftq-sQqJYwUdrdbbr9jz3p4AWos
06-14 00:18:33.310   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$TextClassifierImpl$iSt_Guet-O6Vtdk0MA4z-Z4lzaM
06-14 00:18:33.310   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$XeE_KI7QgMKzF9vYRSoFWAolyuA
06-14 00:18:33.310   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.-$$Lambda$jJq8RXuVdjYF3lPq-77PEw1NJLM
06-14 00:18:33.310   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.ActionsModelParamsSupplier$ActionsModelParams
06-14 00:18:33.310   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.ActionsModelParamsSupplier$SettingsObserver
06-14 00:18:33.310   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.ActionsModelParamsSupplier
06-14 00:18:33.310   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.ActionsSuggestionsHelper$PersonEncoder
06-14 00:18:33.310   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.ActionsSuggestionsHelper
06-14 00:18:33.310   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.GenerateLinksLogger$LinkifyStats
06-14 00:18:33.310   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.GenerateLinksLogger
06-14 00:18:33.314   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.ModelFileManager$ModelFile
06-14 00:18:33.314   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.ModelFileManager$ModelFileSupplierImpl
06-14 00:18:33.314   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.ModelFileManager
06-14 00:18:33.314   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager$SettingsObserver
06-14 00:18:33.317   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifierEventTronLogger
06-14 00:18:33.318   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifierImpl
06-14 00:18:33.318   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.intent.-$$Lambda$LabeledIntent$LaL7EfxShgNu4lrdo3mv85g49Jg
06-14 00:18:33.318   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.intent.ClassificationIntentFactory
06-14 00:18:33.318   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.intent.LabeledIntent$Result
06-14 00:18:33.318   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.intent.LabeledIntent$TitleChooser
06-14 00:18:33.318   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.intent.LabeledIntent
06-14 00:18:33.318   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.intent.LegacyClassificationIntentFactory
06-14 00:18:33.319   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.intent.TemplateClassificationIntentFactory
06-14 00:18:33.319   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.intent.TemplateIntentFactory
06-14 00:18:33.319   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.logging.SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent
06-14 00:18:33.319   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.textclassifier.logging.SmartSelectionEventTracker
06-14 00:18:33.323   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.-$$Lambda$yIdmBO6ZxaY03PGN08RySVVQXuE
06-14 00:18:33.329   378   503 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.343   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.392   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.policy.-$$Lambda$PhoneWindow$9SyKQeTuaYx7qUIMJIr4Lk2OpYw
06-14 00:18:33.394   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneSwitcher$WfAxZbJDpCUxBytiUchQ87aGijQ
06-14 00:18:33.431   378   503 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.449   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.531   378   503 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.550   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.633   378   503 W ServiceManager: Service package_native didn't start. Returning NULL
06-14 00:18:33.633   378   503 E storaged: getService package_native failed
06-14 00:18:33.650   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:33.735   333   333 D SurfaceFlinger: Detected janky event. Missed frames: 2
06-14 00:18:33.751   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:34.162   368   368 I chatty  : uid=1071(iorapd) /system/bin/iorapd identical 4 lines
06-14 00:18:34.263   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:34.352   333   333 D SurfaceFlinger: Detected janky event. Missed frames: 1
06-14 00:18:34.365   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:34.465   368   368 I chatty  : uid=1071(iorapd) /system/bin/iorapd identical 1 line
06-14 00:18:34.566   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:34.569   333   333 D SurfaceFlinger: Detected janky event. Missed frames: 3
06-14 00:18:34.670   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:34.719   333   333 D SurfaceFlinger: Detected janky event. Missed frames: 3
06-14 00:18:34.788   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:34.869   333   333 D SurfaceFlinger: Detected janky event. Missed frames: 3
06-14 00:18:34.889   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:34.989   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:35.002   333   333 D SurfaceFlinger: Detected janky event. Missed frames: 1
06-14 00:18:35.098   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:35.132   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.telephony.NitzStateMachineImpl
06-14 00:18:35.133   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.telephony.Phone$1
06-14 00:18:35.141   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.telephony.TimeServiceHelper
06-14 00:18:35.142   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.telephony.TimeZoneLookupHelper$CountryResult
06-14 00:18:35.142   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.telephony.TimeZoneLookupHelper
06-14 00:18:35.147   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTracker$6
06-14 00:18:35.147   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTracker$DctOnSubscriptionsChangedListener
06-14 00:18:35.161   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.telephony.imsphone.ImsPhone$5
06-14 00:18:35.165   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.telephony.nitz.NewNitzStateMachineImpl
06-14 00:18:35.188   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.util.ScreenshotHelper$2$1
06-14 00:18:35.190   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.view.IInputContextCallback$Stub$Proxy
06-14 00:18:35.190   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.view.IInputContextCallback$Stub
06-14 00:18:35.190   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.view.IInputContextCallback
06-14 00:18:35.190   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.view.InputConnectionWrapper$InputContextCallback
06-14 00:18:35.191   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.view.SurfaceFlingerVsyncChoreographer
06-14 00:18:35.191   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.view.animation.FallbackLUTInterpolator
06-14 00:18:35.191   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.view.animation.HasNativeInterpolator
06-14 00:18:35.191   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.view.animation.NativeInterpolatorFactory
06-14 00:18:35.191   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.android.internal.view.animation.NativeInterpolatorFactoryHelper
06-14 00:18:35.198   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:35.231   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.ActionsSuggestionsModel$ActionSuggestion
06-14 00:18:35.231   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.ActionsSuggestionsModel$Conversation
06-14 00:18:35.231   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.ActionsSuggestionsModel$ConversationMessage
06-14 00:18:35.231   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.ActionsSuggestionsModel
06-14 00:18:35.231   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.AnnotatorModel$AnnotatedSpan
06-14 00:18:35.231   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.AnnotatorModel$AnnotationOptions
06-14 00:18:35.231   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.AnnotatorModel$AnnotationUsecase
06-14 00:18:35.231   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.AnnotatorModel$ClassificationResult
06-14 00:18:35.231   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.AnnotatorModel
06-14 00:18:35.231   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.LangIdModel$LanguageResult
06-14 00:18:35.231   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.LangIdModel
06-14 00:18:35.232   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.NamedVariant
06-14 00:18:35.232   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: com.google.android.textclassifier.RemoteActionTemplate
06-14 00:18:35.262   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: libcore.timezone.ZoneInfoDB$1
06-14 00:18:35.262   289   289 W Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: libcore.timezone.ZoneInfoDB
06-14 00:18:35.282   289   289 I Zygote  : ...preloaded 11718 classes in 4485ms.
06-14 00:18:35.282   289   289 I zygote  : VMRuntime.preloadDexCaches starting
06-14 00:18:35.299   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:35.333   289   289 I zygote  : VMRuntime.preloadDexCaches strings total=415462 before=11141 after=11141
06-14 00:18:35.333   289   289 I zygote  : VMRuntime.preloadDexCaches types total=40712 before=10255 after=10443
06-14 00:18:35.333   289   289 I zygote  : VMRuntime.preloadDexCaches fields total=172454 before=12924 after=13718
06-14 00:18:35.333   289   289 I zygote  : VMRuntime.preloadDexCaches methods total=314173 before=17407 after=17407
06-14 00:18:35.333   289   289 I zygote  : VMRuntime.preloadDexCaches finished
06-14 00:18:35.333   289   289 D Zygote32Timing: PreloadClasses took to complete: 4536ms
06-14 00:18:35.343   289   289 I zygote  : The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
06-14 00:18:35.344   289   289 D ApplicationLoaders: Created zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar
06-14 00:18:35.356   289   289 I zygote  : The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
06-14 00:18:35.357   289   289 D ApplicationLoaders: Created zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.jar
06-14 00:18:35.357   289   289 D Zygote32Timing: CacheNonBootClasspathClassLoaders took to complete: 24ms
06-14 00:18:35.357   289   289 I Zygote  : Preloading resources...
06-14 00:18:35.393   289   289 W Resources: Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080288 (android:drawable/dialog_background_material) that varies with configuration!!
06-14 00:18:35.409   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:35.421   289   289 I Zygote  : ...preloaded 64 resources in 64ms.
06-14 00:18:35.427   289   289 I Zygote  : ...preloaded 41 resources in 6ms.
06-14 00:18:35.427   289   289 D Zygote32Timing: PreloadResources took to complete: 70ms
06-14 00:18:35.461   289   289 I Zygote  : Preloading shared libraries...
06-14 00:18:35.515   368   368 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
06-14 00:18:35.543   289   289 I Zygote  : Called ZygoteHooks.endPreload()
06-14 00:18:35.544   289   289 I Zygote  : Installed AndroidKeyStoreProvider in 0ms.
06-14 00:18:35.551   289   289 I Zygote  : Warmed up JCA providers in 8ms.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: have you enabled virtualization in bios?